# Are sql triggers run in a separate thread?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

If I want to return the user a web page and write to a log or word by word processing, should I use a stored procedure call from CLR in a new thread or just use sql triggers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a SQL Server trigger run asyncronously.  The best you could do is utilize SQL Server's Service Broker to execute a stored proc call.

Comment: I used threads using c# and they work fine, but i was wondering if triggers do that for me. it would save me time. your reply seems to reply my question. But Does ADO.net return results after stored procedure call or does it wait until all triggers are executed?

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan I am positive that an `INSTEAD OF` trigger is definitely syncronous to the data flow, but let me test it out with an `AFTER` trigger.  That's a good question, I'll let you know.

Comment: @Uğur Gümüşhan: ADO is not SQL and SQL is not ADO.

Comment: @Surfer513: **all** triggers are synchronous, and run as part of the DML. Which includes the transaction being open. And long running or complex logic etc should outside of the transaction if needed: either in a stored proc or by using SB to decouple the 2 (as you noted)